# for key in keys: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python-3.x

I know that this error message 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable' means that there is None is the data. However, I am looking through all of my list and there is no part which has a no value element. This is the section of my code that correlates to my issue.

```
url = input('\nEnter URL Here: ')
type_url = url.split('?')[0].split('/')[-1]

if type_url == 'tv-guide':
    id_url = url.split('=')[-1]
else:
    id_url = url.split('&')[0].split('=')[-1]

#id_url = url.split('&')[0].split('=')[-1]
#fix_id = id_url.split('=')[-1]
resp = requests.post('https://tvapi-sgn.solocoo.tv/v1/assets/{}/play'.format(id_url), headers=headers, json=json_data).json()
lic_url = resp['drm']['licenseUrl']
mpd_url = resp['url']

print(f'\nMPD URL: {mpd_url}')
print(f'\nLICENSE URL: {lic_url}')

def get_pssh_kid(keyId):
    array_of_bytes = bytearray( b'\x00\x00\x002pssh\x00\x00\x00\x00')
    array_of_bytes.extend(bytes.fromhex("edef8ba979d64acea3c827dcd51d21ed"))
    array_of_bytes.extend(b'\x00\x00\x00\x12\x12\x10')
    array_of_bytes.extend(bytes.fromhex(keyId.replace("-", "")))
    return base64.b64encode(bytes.fromhex(array_of_bytes.hex()))

def get_pssh_mpd(mpd_url):
    r = requests.get(url=mpd_url)
    r.raise_for_status()
    xml = xmltodict.parse(r.text)
    mpd = json.loads(json.dumps(xml))
    tracks = mpd['MPD']['Period']['AdaptationSet']
    for video_tracks in tracks:
        if video_tracks['@mimeType'] == 'video/mp4':
            for t in video_tracks["ContentProtection"]:
                if t['@schemeIdUri'].lower() == "urn:mpeg:dash:mp4protection:2011":
                    kid = t['@cenc:default_KID']
                    pssh = get_pssh_kid(kid)
    return pssh

pssh = get_pssh_mpd(mpd_url).decode('utf-8')

print("\n[green]+ [INFO] PSSH: [/green]" + pssh)

def decrypt_keys():
    wvdecrypt = WvDecrypt(pssh)
    raw_challenge = wvdecrypt.get_challenge()
    challenge_b64 = b64encode(raw_challenge).decode()
    widevine_license = requests.post(
        url=lic_url, data=raw_challenge, headers=headers, timeout=10)
    license_b64 = b64encode(widevine_license.content)
    wvdecrypt.update_license(license_b64)
    keys = wvdecrypt.start_process()
    if keys:
        return keys

keys = decrypt_keys()

for key in keys:
    print("\n[green]+ [INFO] KEY: --key [/green]" + key)
```

I want my code to do the same output without the error message. Do you know what part of the list could have 'None'? Thank you :)
and this is the error i get:

```
+ [INFO] PSSH: AAAAMnBzc2gAAAAA7e+LqXnWSs6jyCfc1R0h7QAAABISEFESrzdJJkwml6zu8TAEfX8=
unable to parse license - check protobufs
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Project\k\l3.py", line 105, in <module>
    for key in keys:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

can someone help me fix that code? Thanks!

Comment: The function `decrypt_keys` does not run through a return statement if `keys` is falsy, so it will return `None` by default. Make sure `wvdecrypt.start_process()` returns a truthy value.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, `wvdecrypt.start_process()` returns None. As you have no default return value, that's what your function returns too. 
If you want to prevent the error from breaking the execution, you could just check if `keys` is defined before the loop:

```py
keys = decrypt_keys()
if keys:
    for key in keys:
        print("\n[green]+ [INFO] KEY: --key [/green]" + key)
```

However, you should probably investigate why `start_process` returns None first.